# How to display even numbers with an alert box in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am still new to Javascript and I need help on how to display all even numbers in a single alert box. When I run the code, it only displays "21".

```js
function myFunction() {
  var i;
  for (i = 2; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0);
  }
  alert(i);
}
```

```html
<h2>Even numbers from two to twenty</h2>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Display</button>
```

Comment: The `alert` is outside the loop

Comment: What do you expect `if(i%2==0);` to do?

Answer (score 1):

The value of i changes everytime the code in the loop is run.
By the time your code gets to the alert() function, the value of i is equal to the last uneven number you encountered.

A way of solving this is by adding all the uneven numbers to an array and then alerting the value of this array.

Like this:

```html
<h2>Even numbers from two to twenty</h2>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Display</button>

<script>
function myFunction(){
  var i;
  uneven = [];

  for (i=2;i<=20;i++){
    if(i%2!=0){
      uneven.push(i);
    }  
  }
  alert(uneven);
}

</script>
```

Every time the loop encounters a number that's uneven, it is added to an array. In the end the array will be a list of uneven numbers. 
If you put this list in the alert() function, you'll get all the uneven numbers.

The modulus operator % also checks the remainder after a division. If the remainder after a division by 2 is 0, the number is **even**. Therefore you should add i to the uneven numbers when `i%2 != 0`. So when it's **not** even.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. You have alert(i); after for loop is ended. So once forloop is finished i = 21.

so change it to

```
for (i=2;i<=20;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0) {
            alert(i);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now all the even numbers pop-up in an alert box 10x consecutively, how do I put them all in one alert box?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h2>Even numbers from two to twenty</h2>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Display</button>
    <script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        var i;
        var evenNo=[];
        for (i=2;i<=20;i++)
        {
            if(i%2==0)
                evenNo.push(i);
        }
            alert(evenNo.join(", "));
    }
    </script>
```